# Web scraping with 'scrapy' crawled 0 pages and items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Im setting up a proxy grabber from one site, but im getting nothing.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

class ProxyServersPro(Item):
    ip = scrapy.Field()
    port = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field()
    speed = scrapy.Field()
    protocol = scrapy.Field()
    anon = scrapy.Field()

class ProxyServersPro(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ProxyServersProCrawler"
    start_urls = ["https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/1"]
    allowed_domains = ['proxyservers.pro']

    rules = {
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'page'), callback = 'parse_item')
        }

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = ItemLoader (ProxyServersPro(), response=response)
    item.add_xpath('ip', '//*[@id="content-content"]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()')
    item.add_xpath('port', '//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span/text()')
    item.add_xpath('country', '//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()')
    item.add_xpath('speed', '//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div[1]/div/div/text()')
    item.add_xpath('protocol', '//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/text()')
    item.add_xpath('anon', '//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/text()')
    return item.load_item()
```

and this is what the console says.

```
2019-03-24 04:53:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

can someone figure out what is going on? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example code please have a look

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest, HtmlResponse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.conf import settings
import urllib
import json
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from requests import Session

from scrapy import Item, Field


class ProxyServersPro(Item):
    ip = Field()
    port = Field()
    country = Field()
    speed = Field()
    protocol = Field()
    anon = Field()
    port = Field()
class ProxyServers(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ProxyServersProCrawler"

    allowed_domains = ['proxyservers.pro']
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    start_url = ['https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/1', 'https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/2', 'https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/3', 'https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/4', 'https://es.proxyservers.pro/proxy/list/speed/2/anonymity/elite/order/duration/order_dir/asc/page/5']

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProxyServers, self).__init__()

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_url:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_companies, headers=self.headers)


    def parse_companies(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//table[@class="table table-hover"]/tbody/tr')
        for data in table:
            ip = data.xpath('./td[2]/a/text()').extract_first()
            country = data.xpath('./td[4]/text()').extract_first()
            protocol = data.xpath('./td[7]/text()').extract_first()
            anon = data.xpath('./td[8]/text()').extract_first()
            port = data.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract_first()

            item = ProxyServersPro()
            item['ip'] = ip
            item['country'] = country
            item['protocol'] = protocol
            item['anon'] = anon
            item['port'] = port
            yield item
```

also port and speed is not in the content of the website, it is loading instantly we can not get through xpath.

Comment: Not working for me... "NameError: name 'Request' is not defined"

Comment: I have edited my answer please check now it should work

Comment: now this is happening
"runspider: error: Unable to load '22.py': No module named 'requests'"

Comment: please install the module requests and then try again, you can install it by using this command
   `pip install requests`

Comment: Okay now its working, but it only extracts one item, how i proceed? Thanks btw

Comment: @MatiasF I have updated my code to get all items on the page please check and mark my answer if it work